# How can I prevent user pages being created for users with a specific role?

Tags: users

I have various users on a Drupal site.

Internally, I differentiate between users by user role (e.g. 'member', 'non-member').

Is it possible that if a user has a certain user role, that I prevent them from having a user page that is visible to the public?

E.g., if user 10018 has user role 'non-member', how can I prevent user page (site.com/user/10018/) from being visible to the public and users of role 'member'?

Basically, I don't want to delete 'non-member' users unless it's absolutely necessary - but I don't want them to have user pages that are visible to anyone other than site admins.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a redirect (possibly to 404) when someone tries to view the user page of a user with a specified role.

Answer (score 0):

I would work with [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7).

Something like, if user we are viewing does not have role Member or user looking isn't admin, prevent access.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [hook_page_build(&$page)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_page_build/7)

1. get user id from url
2. load user object using user_load()
3. check the user role
4. change the page content as you need